# PHP curl not working when url have .jpg and post fields

Tags: php, curl

I am using php curl to ping and post data to a url. But it is not working.response of url is "not found" this comes when the posting url is "http://example.com/conversion_get/" 
I suspect it was because of .jpg in curl url.
 I am using same code in same application to post data. but it works fine. Can any body help me to sort out this issue?

My code:

```
    $kps="6789345607655ABF5k23929ocern46789345607655ABF5k23929ocern4";
    $url="http://example.com/conversion_get/pixel.jpg";
    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!$ch){die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");}
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "kp=".$kps);
    $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $curlresponse = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    if(curl_errno($ch))
    echo 'curl error : '. curl_error($ch);
    if (empty($ret)) {
    curl_close($ch);
    } else {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
    $ns= $curlresponse; 
       }
```

Comment: If you get "not found", it means that the URL is invalid.  You need to make sure that the whole URL is correct - nobody can help you with this.  My advice is to install a browser extension like postman, then use it to send exactly the same request - with copy/paste of url and parameters - and debug it that way.

Comment: Additionally, if you're dealing with a REST-like API, "not found" response may mean that you're sending unknown parameters - check those as well.

Comment: but when we access http://example.com/conversion_get/pixel.jpg?kp=6789345607655ABF5k23929ocern46789345607655ABF5k23929ocern4, it is working fine...

Comment: How do you access it?  Using post with the same parameters or using get?  That's why I said that you need to use something like postmant - simply putting the url in the browser is _not_ the same thing.

Comment: no just clicking the url, it shows OK response

Comment: so it act as get request

Comment: Again, this is not the same thing.  Just because http://www.google.com works, doesn't mean that http://www.googlewerqfasdfaswef.com will work - you are comparing two completely different requests.

Comment: also not found response is coming from pinging url   "http://example.com/conversion_get/" ... I think balance part of this url  pixel.jpg&kp=<value> not taking

Comment: It looks like you're doing a POST instead of GET.  Change `CURLOPT_URL` to `http://example.com/conversion_get/pixel.jpg?kp=678.....rn4` and remove CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: "kp=".$kps);  isn't encoded properly. try http_build_query(array('kp'=>$kps)));

Comment: should I give like this ? : curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    http_build_query(array('kp'=>$kps)));